# Testing application using a stub server in jetty

Tags: java, testing, jetty, integration-testing

I'm writing tests for an application that accesses web services over http. I'd like to create a stub server where I can verify the request that came from the client app and send a stub response. I'm trying to use jetty but its API documentation is quite lacking.
I'd like to have something, where I can fetch and parse an HTTP request from the socket stream, send a stub response and introspect the request. Here is a dummy code where I test if the client sent a correct header:

```java
public class MyTestSuite {
  ServerSocket serverSock;
  ExecutorService executor;

  @BeforeMethod
  public void setupServerSocket() throws IOException {
    serverSock = new ServerSocket(0);
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void teardownServerSocket() throws IOException {
    serverSock.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    Future<HttpField> result = executor.submit(() -> {
      try (Socket sock = serverSock.accept()) {
        // I need a way to create a request from the stream
        Request req = ...;
        // I need to initialize and send a response stub
        Response rep = ...;
        sock.getOutputStream().write(...);
        // ...and return any value I want to inspect
        return req.getField("Content-Type");
      }
    });
    clientUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
    var field = result.get();
    assertEquals(field.getHeader(), HttpHeader.CONTENT_TYPE);
    assertEquals(field.getValue(), "application/json");
  }
}
```

jetty's `HttpTester` and `HttpParser` look like the way to go, but they are quite poorly documented. Is it even the right way to stub the server?

Comment: doing this at the headers level is insufficient, the HttpTester / HttpParser doesn't take into account content encoding, transfer encoding, and similar concepts.    It would be easier to just start an embedded jetty server and write your handler to suite your needs.   Quick startup too.

Comment: I agree, starting up the server and writing handlers seems much nicer to me but I had two issues with that. 1. starting the server in @BeforeXXX and then adding handlers in tests throw IllegalStateException. 2. I can't make assertions (or return values) in the handlers.

Comment: You can [`startServer(Handler)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/search?q=startServer) in your testcase, or you can use `HandlerCollection(true)`, or you can make your `Handler` just delegate to your testcase's specific rules.  Having assertions in Handlers is common too.  The Jetty source is littered with all of these behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to to use the `startServer(Handler)` technique.

```java
package jetty;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestingExampleStartServer
{
    private static Server server;
    private URI serverBaseURI;

    public void startServer(Handler handler) throws Exception
    {
        server = new Server(0);
        server.setHandler(handler);
        server.start();
        serverBaseURI = server.getURI().resolve("/");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopServer()
    {
        LifeCycle.stop(server);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandler() throws Exception
    {
        startServer(new AbstractHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            {
                // do something custom here
                response.setHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                // assert here if you want
            }
        });
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
            .newBuilder(serverBaseURI)
            .GET()
            .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        assertEquals("Bar", response.headers().firstValue("X-Foo").orElse(null));
    }
}
```

Another is to just let the `HandlerCollection` add at will

```java
package jetty;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestingExampleMutableCollection
{
    private static Server server;
    private static URI serverBaseURI;
    private static HandlerCollection handlers;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void startServer() throws Exception
    {
        server = new Server(0);
        handlers = new HandlerCollection(true);
        server.setHandler(handlers);
        server.start();
        serverBaseURI = server.getURI().resolve("/");
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopServer()
    {
        LifeCycle.stop(server);
    }

    private void setHandler(Handler ... handlerList)
    {
        // use .setHandlers(Handler[]) to reset the list, removing other handlers already present.
        handlers.setHandlers(handlerList);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandler() throws Exception
    {
        setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            {
                // do something custom here
                response.setHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                // assert here if you want
            }
        });
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
            .newBuilder(serverBaseURI)
            .GET()
            .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
        assertEquals("Bar", response.headers().firstValue("X-Foo").orElse(null));
    }

}
```

But the easiest is to not use `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` and use a unique server instance per-test. (startup of Jetty is sub 100ms)

```java
package jetty;

import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class TestingExampleLocalServer
{
    @Test
    public void testHandler() throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(0);
        server.setHandler(new AbstractHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            {
                // do something custom here
                response.setHeader("X-Foo", "Bar");
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                // assert here if you want
            }
        });
        server.start();
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder(server.getURI().resolve("/"))
                .GET()
                .build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            assertEquals(200, response.statusCode());
            assertEquals("Bar", response.headers().firstValue("X-Foo").orElse(null));
        }
        finally
        {
            LifeCycle.stop(server);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution defeats the purpose of having setup and teardown methods which are meant to prepare the test environment and tidy it up after the test automatically, without worrying about exceptions and test results. In your answer I need to repeat all that stuff manually in every single test. Also, I can't make assertions inside handlers as they run in a different thread than the test. Failed assertions in handlers are not considered failures.

Comment: failed assertions in handlers report to the junit framework for capture, and also produce a non-200 response on the client causing an additional failure on the asking side.  When testing a server in a unit test, it's often not advisable to have a single instance for multiple `@Test` calls via the `@BeforeAll`, as a state change in one test can fail other tests accidentally.  It's advisable to use `@BeforeEach` to avoid this kind of contamination between tests.

Comment: I'm using testng which doesn't capture assertions from other threads than main. Do you mean I shouldn't reuse the server across multiple tests or just handlers? I'm creating new handler for each tests, but I don't see why re-using the server would be a problem?

Comment: Lots of things on the server side can hold state between requests and can impact behavior in test cases (caches, sessions, persistent stores, the various pools, persistent connections, etc).    Build/Start/Test/Stop the server for each test is what I'm recommending for reliable tests.  Jetty has super fast startup, so this should have minimal impact on your testing.   Never used testng, I'm a junit5 user myself.